# How to parse date with minutes contains value 60?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I am getting exception when the minute contains value 60

```
var date = "30/10/14 08:60";
var result = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "dd/MM/yy HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
```

How do i parse it correctly??

Comment: why not `var date = "30/10/14 09:00";`

Comment: @chouaib Because he would loose the 61st minute he just invented ;-)

Comment: Its the input i am getting .I have no control over the input

Comment: `I am getting exception when the minute contains value 60` ... and rightly so because that is an exceptional circumstance.

Comment: @user3564347 Yes you do, validation, feedback, and at the very least, exceptions.

Comment: Wrong input = exception ! Not your problem to fix it, user has to know that there is no such time as 08:60. User can not expect the application to work if he makes mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you always know if the time portion of your `date` string is of the format HH:mm, you can do this to get the right `DateTime date`:

```
    string dateString = "30/10/14 08:60";
    string[] dateParts = dateString.Split(' ');
    DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(dateParts[0],"dd/MM/yy",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    string[] timeParts = dateParts[1].Split(':');
    date=date.AddMinutes(double.Parse(timeParts[0])*60+double.Parse(timeParts[1]));
```

Answer (score 3):

Either pass a correct value(`>=0 || <=59`) or use this:

```
var date = "30/10/14 08:60";
DateTime dateResult;
bool canParse = DateTime.TryParseExact(date, "dd/MM/yy HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dateResult);
if (!canParse)
{
    string datePart = date.Split().First();
    DateTime dtOnly;
    if (DateTime.TryParseExact(datePart, "dd/MM/yy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dtOnly))
    {
        string timePart = date.Split().Last();
        string hourPart = timePart.Split(':')[0];
        string minutePart = timePart.Split(':').Last();
        int hour, minute;
        if (int.TryParse(hourPart, out hour) && int.TryParse(minutePart, out minute))
        {
            TimeSpan timeOfDay = TimeSpan.FromHours(hour) + TimeSpan.FromMinutes(minute);
            dateResult = dtOnly + timeOfDay;  // 10/30/2014 09:00:00
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all, the data is invalid, and this is why an exception is raised.

So, basically there are 2 resolutions:

1. If the data is from the 3rd party, my suggestion is that after consulting with your boss or company's lawyers you/your company asks the 3rd party to provide valid data, since you don't have legal obligation to fix/tolerate the invalid data for the 3rd party. IMO, you shouldn't.
2. If the data is from your legacy internal systems, you/company should fix the bugs that may produce 60. If for some reasons the bugs can't be fixed shortly, you may write a parser for example using regular expression to parse the data and tolerate 60.

So the 2nd resolution with regular expression is to answer your question directly. However, please be mindful that "30/10/14 08:60" is invalid, and must be fixed sooner or later in the data source.

BTW, here's the link with [some regular expressions](http://www.regxlib.com/%28X%281%29A%28ZRrZ3i1bQaBN9xwze3HVX4hALbf9vvk9swAbuPv9K3n_kHQWSJAiu16UFNQCJhaoILfSSeORdKOBJSOLOlIInZyLxgftcB3tnOop3CW2HvJ2CZw1sDI0at-FgvJsOfCOtsWROqjn8xhHluvhWL2zpkv-4nhSmKYqxPLteLfk3fH3_W5s4JClOiw5HQwWa8If0%29%29/Search.aspx?k=datetime&c=-1&m=-1&ps=20) you may try.

Answer (score 2):

For international convention are 60 minutes in an hour.
The sixtieth minute would be 59, in fact if you count from 0 to 59 find that they are 60 numbers. The date you write 8:60 does not exist, the value of them is 9:00.

Try this(Obviously only date1 raises an exception):

```
var date = "30/10/14  8:59";
var date1 = "30/10/14 9:00";


var result = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "dd/MM/yy HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
var result1 = DateTime.ParseExact(date1, "dd/MM/yy HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
```

In addition at this you can use this for controlling a data and receiving a message true/false

```
var date = "30/10/14 08:60";
DateTime outData;
Boolean flagCorrectData = DateTime.TryParseExact(date, "dd/MM/yy HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out outData);
     if (flagCorrectData)
     {
        MessageBox.Show("Date correct");
     }
     else
     {
        MessageBox.Show("Date error");
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only care precisely about the special case of :60, you can use 60 in `ParseExact` explicitly:

```
string date = "30/10/14 08:60";
DateTime result;

if(DateTime.TryParseExact(date, "dd/MM/yy HH:mm", 
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None,out result)) 
{
    return result;
}    

//Handle weird :60
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(date, "dd/MM/yy HH:60",
        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None,out result))
{
    return result.AddMinutes(60);
}

throw new ArgumentException("date");
```